Does the Cruciatus curse leave a physical mark?
It is mentioned several times throughout the series that the Killing curse leaves no noticeable mark. It's also presumable that the Imperius curse leaves no mark either.
Along the same lines, does the Cruciatus curse leave any physical mark or is it plain pain?

https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Cruciatus_Curse#Nature

Whilst the spell might leave no mark, I'm sure the other injuries it could cause due to flinging some about might leave bruising, injuries, etc: "Harry shouted, "Crucio!". The Death Eater was lifted off his feet. He writhed through the air like a drowning man, thrashing and howling in pain, and then, with a crunch and a shattering of glass, he smashed into the front of a bookcase and crumpled, insensible, to the floor."

In any of the original material, I can think of no place where it said the Cruciatus curse left a physical mark. However, the spells effects can be long term. The Longbottom's were victims of the spell over a long period of time and were permanently affected by it (driven crazy). While this didn't leave a mark like Harry's scar it did or can leave a permanent effect.

I read somewhere that the Cruciatus curse affects the nerve endings causing them to send signals of pain back to the brain. Prolonged usage could cause brain haemorrhage and therefore internal injuries but nothing external. Most fanfiction and some canon-sites have it that the nerve endings will forever be damaged and victims will have tremors, constant nerve pain and deadening of limbs.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you find any quotes from canon sources to back this up?  Direct quotes are a lot better evidence than "I read this somewhere."
